# Downloading a file on my website, with and without a secret. A room for improvement?

Tags: tls, web-application, http

I'm trying to create a simple download system as a part of my website.  Is there anything insecure in this route:

```
 GET https://my_website.com/downloads?file_id=AAA&user_id=BBB&secret=CCC
```

Where user_id and code are optional for files that are free to download. 
Otherwise, after a payment I generate a unique code/secret for a user and provide him a link.

Is there room for improvement here? And are there vulnerabilities?

**It's not just a random url**

**There'll also be "expire_date" associated with each secret.**

Comment: I think there are more duplicates out there if you search for "random url" or "unguessable url".

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts:

1. URLs get logged and remembered all over the place (server and proxy logs, browser history, search crawlers, etc.), so unless the link is very ephemeral (short-lived), you should assume the links will leak and can't be used to provide a *lot* of security. If you want actual authentication, you should either set a cookie (securely) and reject requests that don't have the expected cookie value, or transmit the secret fields in a POST body, or otherwise keep the secrets out of the URL.
2. Obviously, the user ID and secret need to be unguessable. That means they need to be long, and securely random. As a general rule, aim for at least 128 bits of entropy; this is more than you strictly need, but it's cheap and may offer some protection against weaknesses elsewhere (though it also may not).
3. I'm actually not sure why you're bothering with a user ID, here; unless the user ID is a reusable identifier that the user gets value out of having remain constant, you may as well just use the secrets.
4. The file *ID*, rather than file *name*, implies that you're not actually having anything the user provides be directly used to build a path into your file system. This is good and right and proper. Do not, if you can help it, provide a way for users to ever specify the names of files directly, as that risks the users gaining access to files you didn't mean them to access.
5. You might want to create a time limit, usage limit, or revocation system for your secret links. Otherwise, once a link is generated, it will stay valid forever even if you want it to stop working (or the user wants it to stop working, for example because it links to something sensitive/private to the user but somebody got their hands on the link).
6. If you have to manually process payments and generate links, that won't scale. Doing it automatically is entirely possible but requires a lot of work to make the payment handling and verification secure.
7. Make sure you're validating the parameters securely. Watch for injection attacks (for example, SQL injection if you're checking against a relational database) and sanitize the fields if you ever reflect them into the page (to prevent cross-site scripting), especially if you use cookies or local storage for anything.
8. Can users also *upload* files? If so, you've got a whole mess of stuff to watch out for, everything from preventing users from uploading malicious or illegal content to ensuring that users don't overwrite important files (potentially gaining control over the webserver) or make the server spend a ton of resources trying to process a really expensive file (like a [compression bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_bomb)).

I'm sure I'd come up with a lot more, but that should be enough to get you started. Security is hard. Trying to make your security system simple doesn't mean it's easy to get it right.

Comment: `Otherwise, once a link is generated, it will stay valid forever even` -- I'll add "expire_date"

Comment: `The file ID, rather than file name, implies that you're not actually having anything the user provides be directly used to build a path into your file system. ` -- but it'll allow a hacker to do the enumeration attack and find out how many files there are

Comment: users will not be allowed  to upload files

Comment: No need (or reason) for file IDs to be sequential. Figuring out how many files there are probably isn't a significant weakness, but why take the risk?

Comment: what risk?............

Comment: @Uji ... the one you mentioned four comments up? `but it'll allow a hacker to do the enumeration attack and find out how many files there are`. No reason to do that if you don't have to. Use non-sequential IDs. The only real requirement is that they not repeat, and I very much doubt you'll have enough files for that to be a real concern if you, for example, give each file a GUID.

Comment: ok, why is it a risk?